# UFT retrieve data from SQL: Item cannot be found in the collection

Tags: sql, automated-tests, qtp

Using UFT12.51. Need to retrieve data from SQL Server.

Same question was asked by many people, but researching several posts, could not find any answer.

The query to run is:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.TempTableOutgoing, TempTableOutgoingLeft, TempTableOutgoingRight;

SELECT Table1.RowNum, Table1.present, Table2.Amount INTO TempTableOutgoingLeft FROM
    (Select cte.* FROM (VALUES ('1','1st Present'), ('2','1P 1-Sided'), ('3','')
    ) as cte (RowNum,present)) AS Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ca.* FROM [eBalance].[dbo].[TRANS_DISTRIB] AS t1
      CROSS APPLY (Values
        ('1',  CONVERT(VARCHAR, FirstPresent)),
        ('2',  CONVERT(VARCHAR, FirstPresentOneSided)),
        ('3',NULL)
        ) AS ca (RowNum, Amount)
    WHERE t1.FileDate = ''"&FileDate&"'' AND t1.CardType = 'AMEX') as Table2
    on Table1.RowNum = Table2.RowNum;

SELECT * INTO TempTableOutgoingRight FROM(
SELECT vi.rownumber, vi.outgoing, vi.oamount FROM [eBalance].[dbo].[AMEX_OUTGOING] AS V1
      CROSS APPLY (Values ('1','Sales', Sales),
                    ('2','Cash Advances', CashAdvances),
                    ('3','Returns', Credits)
            ) as vi (rownumber, outgoing, oamount)
WHERE v1.FileDate = ''"&FileDate&"'')R;

SELECT RowNum, Present, Amount, Outgoing, OAmount INTO TempTableOutgoing FROM(
SELECT * FROM(SELECT * FROM TempTableOutgoingLeft
UNION ALL
SELECT '4','Total',  CONVERT(VARCHAR, SUM(CAST(ISNULL(Amount,'0') AS decimal(15,2)))) from TempTableOutgoingLeft) AS Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM TempTableOutgoingRight
UNION ALL
SELECT '4','Outgoing Settlement Total',  CONVERT(VARCHAR, SUM(CAST(ISNULL(oamount,'0') AS decimal(15,2)))) from TempTableOutgoingRight) AS Table2
ON Table1.RowNum = Table2.rownumber) Z;

DROP TABLE TempTableOutgoingLeft;
DROP TABLE TempTableOutgoingRight;

SELECT present, Amount, Outgoing, OAmount, Variance FROM(
SELECT * FROM dbo.TempTableOutgoing z1
INNER JOIN (Select RowN, Variance from (
SELECT DISTINCT RowN, Variance FROM TempTableOutgoing AS TTO
     CROSS APPLY (Values 
        ('1',''),('2', (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, SUM(CAST(ISNULL(Amount,'0') AS decimal(15,2)))-SUM(CAST(ISNULL(OAmount,'0') AS decimal(15,2))))
        FROM TempTableOutgoing where RowNum IN (1,2,3))), ('3','')) 
        as z (RowN,Variance)    where TTO.RowNum IN (1,2,3)
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT z.* FROM TempTableOutgoing AS TTO
     CROSS APPLY (Values 
        ('4', (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, SUM(CAST(ISNULL(Amount,'0') AS decimal(15,2)))-SUM(CAST(ISNULL(OAmount,'0') AS decimal(15,2))))
        FROM TempTableOutgoing where RowNum IN (4)))
        ) as z (RowN,Variance)  where TTO.RowNum IN (4)
) V Group by RowN, Variance) V1
on z1.RowNum = V1.RowN) T;
```

When running in SQL Management Studio, it works well and gives proper result:

```
present     |Amount     |Outgoing                 |OAmount    |Variance
============+===========+=========================+===========+========
1st Present |5028510.18 |Sales                    |5110968.89
------------+-----------+-------------------------+-----------+--------
1P 1-Sided  |0.00       |Cash Advances            |0.00       |0.00
------------+-----------+-------------------------+-----------+--------
            |NULL       |Returns                  |-82458.71  |
------------+-----------+-------------------------+-----------+--------
Total       |5028510.18 |Outgoing Settlement Total|5028510.18 |0.00
```

But when UFT runs the query, it returns error message while retrieving information:

```
print objRS.Fields(1)
```

> Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested
>   name or ordinal

Printing `err.number` returns ***0***:

```
objConnection.Open "Provider=sqloledb.1; Server=server;User Id=userid; Password=password; Database=database"
Set objRS = objConnection.Execute(query)
print err.number
print objRS.state
print objConnection.state
```

> 0
>
> 0
>
> 0

The connection settings are 100% good, and even a simple query like `SELECT * from [database].[schema].[table]` and `print recordset.fields(0)` returns a valid result.

As far as I researched, problem might cause when the query has more than one column with same name, but that is not my case.

What can be the problem?

Comment: What about print objRS.Fields("Amount") ?

Comment: Same error message((

Comment: Can you debug and see the members of the colletion fields?

Comment: I guess that was a question I did not understand how to do )))